# How to change directory to a filename with spaces within a loop

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory

I'm not sure how to go about this, but I've been trying to loop through different directories to make a number of files.

Example: In the current directory, there are 3 directories:

1. Roman Empire
2. Casa Loma
3. Eiffel Tower

My intention is to **cd** into each directory (**using a loop and variables just in case that the directory names ever get changed**) in shell script to make new folders, but I've been having a bit of issues with the spacing part when calling **cd**.

Calling the name of the code Code, here's what I've tried so far:

```
declare -a place
for d in */
do
    place=("${place[@]}" "$d")
done

number=($(ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l))
```

Here, we save the names of the directories

1. Roman Empire/
2. Casa Loma/
3. Eiffel Tower/

And **number** saves the number of directories in the given directory, and in this case: 3.

```
for (( k=0 ; k < ${number} ; k++ ))
do
    echo " This is place: ${place[k]} "
    cd ${place[k]}

    # Creating new files are not shown

    cd ..
done
```

This results in:

```
 This is place: Roman Empire/ 
./Code.sh: line 4: cd: Roman: No such file or directory
```

Any help and pointers on how to go about this would be great

Comment: Use double quotes: `cd "${place[k]}"`.

Comment: Each time you use a filename or a dirname, put double quotes around your variables like this: `cd "${place[k]}"`. It's mandatory with destructive commands (cp, mv, rm...) or with redirections (>, >>)

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is because in bash (and *most* other shells) expansions of the form `$var` or `${var}` are subject to word splitting (and filename generation aka globbing, although that's not an issue here) - see [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

However you could simplify your code a lot.

1. there's no need for an explicit loop to place the directory list into an array; you can just do

   ```
   shopt -s nullglob
   place=( */ )
   ```

   If you prefer to do a loop, then a simpler way to append items is

   ```
   place=()
   for d in */; do
     place+=("$d")
   done
   ```
2. There's no need to do ugly stuff like parsing the output of `ls` to get the count, since you can get that from the array directly as `${#place[@]}`. So

   ```
   ndirs=${#place[@]}
   for ((k=0; k<ndirs; k++)); do
     cd "${place[k]}"
     # do stuff
     cd -
   done
   ```

   Note that neither `ndirs` inside `(( ... ))` nor `k` inside `${place[k]}` need explicit `$` to dereference them since these are both arithmetic evaluation contexts.
3. You don't really even need a C-style loop, you could just do

   ```
   shopt -s nullglob
   place=( */ )

   for p in "${place[@]}"; do
     cd "$p"
     # do stuff
     cd -
   done
   ```

   (or just `for p in */; do ...` if you don't need the array for any other purpose).