# How to copy an existing specific file in a directory into a newly created subdirectory from command prompt using shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, copy

I'm having a little issues trying to make a copy of a pre-existing file (specifically java) from the current directory to a subdirectory (and some copies to its subdirectory and so on depending on the command), I know it may sound simple, but it kind of gets complicated (for me at least) when we go into more detail.

For example, we're given a directory:

```
├── Main
│   ├── Initial.java                  # Initial java file that was already there
│   ├── Then.java                     # Then java file that was already there
```

Here we have an example of what we would have type in the terminal based on the instructions:

```
./Code NewSubDir1.NewSubDir2.Initial NewSubDir1.Then
```

Where Code is the .sh file name. Every argument is supposed to a directory path until we get to a file name, where in this case, we would have **Initial** and **Then**.

The following is the expected output:

```
├── Main
│   ├── Initial.java                  # Initial java file that was already there
│   ├── Then.java                     # Then java file that was already there
│   ├── NewSubDir1.                   # Newly Created Subdirectory from command
│   │   ├── Initial.java              # Copied java file from Initial.java
│   │   ├── NewSubDir2                # Newly Created Subdirectory from command
│   │   │   ├── Then.java             # Copied java file from Then.java
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

I've already coded how to get the subdirectories, so I've got

```
├── Main
│   ├── Initial.java                  # Initial java file that was already there
│   ├── Then.java                     # Then java file that was already there
│   ├── NewSubDir1.                   # Newly Created Subdirectory from command
│   │   ├── NewSubDir2                # Newly Created Subdirectory from command
```

Now, getting to the copy part has been a bit tricky:

```
# An array of the arguments
declare -a directory
IFS=' ' read -r -a directory <<< "$*"

# Pre-existing java files
javaFiles=($(ls *.java))


for (( i=0 ; i < ${args} ; i++ ))
do
            # Get wanted filename from command prompt (EXAMPLE: Initial)
            copyFile=${directory[i]##*.}

            dir=${directory[i]%.*}
            path=${dir//[.]//}
            echo $path

            for (( j=0 ; j < ${#javaFiles} ; j++ ))
            do

                javaName=${javaFiles[j]%%.*}

                if [[ "${javaFiles[$j]}" == "${copyFile[$i]}" ]]
                then

                    # I know this part is wrong, but I hope this will give an idea on what I'm trying to do
                    cp "${javaFiles[j]}" "$path"
                fi
            done
            
            # Other code is not shown
done
```

Comment: `IFS=' ' read -r -a directory <<< "$*"` is going to have the same issue with word splitting that you encountered in [How to change directory to a filename with spaces within a loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489914/how-to-change-directory-to-a-filename-with-spaces-within-a-loop) - if you want to copy a script's command line arguments to a named array, just use `directory=("$@")`

Comment: ... and for similar reasons never use `javaFiles=($(ls *.java))`, it should be `javaFiles=(*.java)`, having set the `nullglob` shell option. See [bash pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Are you sure you have the arguments right? You show `./Code NewSubDir1.NewSubDir2.Initial NewSubDir1.Then` but then you create `NewSubDir1./Initial.java` and `NewSubDir1./NewSubDir2/Then.java`. Shouldn't the original input have been `NewSubDir1.Initial` and `NewSubDir1.NewSubDir2.Then`? Also, can't you use `/` instead of `.` for this? Is using `.` a requirement or can the argument be the actual path that needs to be created (e.g. `NewSubDir1/NewSubDir2/Then`?